# Best way to update a dataframe in Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Consider two Dataframe `data_df` and `update_df`. These two dataframes have the same schema `(key, update_time, bunch of columns)`.

I know two (main) way to "update" `data_df` with `update_df`

1. **full outer join**
   I join the two dataframes (on key) and then pick the appropriate columns (according to the value of update_timestamp)
2. **max over partition**
   Union both dataframes, compute the max update_timestamp by key and then filter only rows that equal this maximum.

Here are the questions :

- Is there any other way ?
- Which one is the best way and why ?

I've already done the comparison with some Open Data
Here is the join code

```
var join_df = data_df.alias("data").join(maj_df.alias("maj"), Seq("key"), "outer")
var res_df = join_df.where( $"data.update_time" > $"maj.update_time" || $"maj.update_time".isNull)
             .select(col("data.*"))
         .union(
         join_df.where( $"data.update_time" < $"maj.update_time" || $"data.update_time".isNull)
             .select(col("maj.*")))
```

And here is window code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

val byKey = Window.partitionBy($"key") // orderBy is implicit here

res_df = data_df.union(maj_df)
                .withColumn("max_version", max("update_time").over(byKey))
                .where($"update_time" === $"max_version")
```

I can paste you DAGs and Plans here if needed, but they are pretty large

My first guess is that the join solution might be the best way but it only works if the `update` dataframe got only one version per key.

---

PS : I'm aware of Apache Delta solution but sadly i'm not able too use it.

Comment: what is Apache Delta?

Comment: https://docs.delta.io/0.4.0/delta-update.html

Answer (score 0):

Below is one way of doing it to only join on the keys, in an effort to minimize the amount of memory to be used on filters and on join commands.

```
///Two records, one with a change, one no change
val originalDF = spark.sql("select 'aa' as Key, 'Joe' as Name").unionAll(spark.sql("select 'cc' as Key, 'Doe' as Name")) 


///Two records, one change, one new
val updateDF =  = spark.sql("select 'aa' as Key, 'Aoe' as Name").unionAll(spark.sql("select 'bb' as Key, 'Moe' as Name"))

///Make new DFs of each just for Key   
val originalKeyDF = originalDF.selectExpr("Key")
val updateKeyDF = updateDF.selectExpr("Key")

///Find the keys that are similar between both
val joinKeyDF = updateKeyDF.join(originalKeyDF, updateKeyDF("Key") === originalKeyDF("Key"), "inner")
///Turn the known keys into an Array
val joinKeyArray = joinKeyDF.select(originalKeyDF("Key")).rdd.map(x=>x.mkString).collect

///Filter the rows from original that are not found in the new file
val originalNoChangeDF = originalDF.where(!($"Key".isin(joinKeyArray:_*)))

///Update the output with unchanged records, update records, and new records
val finalDF = originalNoChangeDF.unionAll(updateDF)
```